# SQL group by query. Aggregate

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, postgresql-9.5

Can you please help me with a group by query. 
I have a table like below

```
Country State      SomeType
UK      England    Yes
UK      Wales      No
UK      Scotland   MayBe
Germany Bavaria    Yes
Germany Bremen     Yes
```

I need to tag each country as Yes, No, MayBe or Mixed type.

If all states are Yes then that country will be Yes, All No then that country will be No, If all are MayBe then that country will be MayBe
But if different states have different SomeType then it should be tagged Mixed

In above case I should get output as

```
Country Type
UK      Mixed
Germany Yes
```

This is just a made up example as I can't give here real requirement. Sorry if someone objects to calling Wales a state instead of constituent country.

Comment: Thanks a ton for quick help. Any more answers are welcome. I will now start using these answers. It has to be compliant for postgres sql.

Answer (score 1):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2cb89bebde9175188c326fb5de18e633)

You can use array aggregation with `array_agg()` and then checking the array values with the `ALL` operator:

```
SELECT
    country,
    CASE 
        WHEN 'Yes' = ALL(array_agg(some_type)) THEN 'Yes' 
        WHEN 'No' = ALL(array_agg(some_type)) THEN 'No'
        ELSE 'Mixed' 
    END as type
FROM mytable
GROUP BY country
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go aggregation :

```
select country, (case when count(distinct sometype) > 1 
                      then 'mixed' 
                      else max(sometype)
                 end) as Type
from table t
group by country;
```

Comment: Thanks Yogesh. I liked this solution. Is it possible to add count on top of Type. I am interested in getting count of Mixed, Yes, No etc. along with what type the count is for. I tried to run below but it complained that aggregate functions can not be nested. 

select  Type, count( (case when count(distinct sometype) > 1 
                      then 'mixed' 
                      else max(sometype)
                 end)) as Type
from table t
group by country;

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation and a conditional expression:

```
select 
    country,
    case 
        when count(*) filter(where sometype = 'No') = 0 then 'Yes'
        when count(*) filter(where sometype = 'Yes') = 0 then 'No'
        else 'Mixed'
    end "type"
from mytable
group by country
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case..when` expression with aggregation :

```
select country, 
       case when sum(case when sometype = 'Yes' then 1 end)=count(*) then max(sometype)
            when sum(case when sometype = 'No' then 1 end)=count(*) then max(sometype)
            when sum(case when sometype = 'MayBe' then 1 end)=count(*) then max(sometype)  
            else
               'Mixed'  
            end as type
  from tab
 group by country
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=2cd3e5c105dc0f0536cd287dc0938487)</kbd>